# Issues with .xlxs file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm having issues with "Cannot get a NUMERIC value from a STRING cell". Sorry for the bad explanation, I am a new student to CS. I have just learned to include Apache POI into the IntelliJ project and finally understanding how to put in the file directory. I still am having issues with the entirety of Apache POI in a whole.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class DataSetTest {
    private static final String EXCEL_FILE_PATH = "C:/Users/assignment/src/dataset.xlsx";
    private static final int NUM_THREADS = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);

        Map<String, Double> userSpendingMap = new HashMap<>();
        double totalMoneySpent = 0.0;

        try (InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(EXCEL_FILE_PATH);
             Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis)) {

            Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            for (Row row : sheet) {
                executorService.execute(() -> processTransaction(row, userSpendingMap));
            }

            executorService.shutdown();

            while (!executorService.isTerminated()) {
                Thread.sleep(100); // Sleep for a short interval to avoid busy waiting
            }

            for (Double amount : userSpendingMap.values()) {
                totalMoneySpent += amount;
            }

            System.out.println("User ID\tTotal Money Spent");
            for (Map.Entry<String, Double> entry : userSpendingMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "\t" + entry.getValue());
            }

            System.out.println("Total money spent by all users: " + totalMoneySpent);

        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void processTransaction(Row row, Map<String, Double> userSpendingMap) {
        Cell userIdCell = row.getCell(1);
        Cell sharePriceCell = row.getCell(2);
        Cell shareBoughtCell = row.getCell(3);

        if (userIdCell != null && sharePriceCell != null && shareBoughtCell != null) {
            String userId = userIdCell.getStringCellValue();
            double sharePrice = sharePriceCell.getNumericCellValue();
            int shareBought = (int) shareBoughtCell.getNumericCellValue();

            double transactionAmount = sharePrice * shareBought;

            synchronized (userSpendingMap) {
                userSpendingMap.put(userId, userSpendingMap.getOrDefault(userId, 0.0) + transactionAmount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html. Especially https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents

Comment: See also [_Can I access/modify workbooks/documents/slideshows in multiple threads?_](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10224)